# Show that $M_{23}$ acts with rank three.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

The following exercise is form P. Cameron, *Permutation Groups*:

> 2.22 The Mathieu group $M_{23}$ is a $4$-transitive permutation group on the set $\Omega = \{1,\ldots, 23\}$, and preserves a set $\mathcal B$ of $253$ subsets of $\Omega$, each of size $7$. *From this information alone*, show that $M_{23}$ acts transitively on $\mathcal B$ with rank $3$.

As the group acts $4$-transitive, among the $4$-subsets of the $7$-subsets in any orbit on $\mathcal B$ appears every possible $4$-subset. As each $7$-subsets can account for at most $\binom{7}{4} = 35$ differnent $4$-subsets, we must have all of the $253$ subsets of $\mathcal B$ in one orbit, for otherwise we do not have enough $7$-subsets to ''fit in'' all $4$-subsets. As $253$ is the least possible value that works for these arguments, every $4$-subsets determines uniquely its $7$-subset in which it is contained, this gives $|A \cap B| \ge 4$ implies $A = B$ for $A,B \in \mathcal B$. The rank for this action on $\mathcal B$ is the number of orbits on $\mathcal B\times \mathcal B$, for $(A,B) \in \mathcal B\times\mathcal B$
the cases $|A\cap B| \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ are possible by the above, and they all give distinct orbits on the cartesian product. Hence the rank is at most $4$, but I still need to argue that one orbit could not arise (and the other three are realised). But here I am stuck. So any ideas how to finish the argument to show that the rank is three?

Comment: You are missing the possibility $A = B$, which gives the orbit $\{(A,A) : A \in \mathcal{B} \}$. So we have $253 \binom{7}{4} = \binom{23}{4}$ and you can see that $\mathcal{B}$ is a $S(4,7,23)$ Steiner system. If you know something about Steiner systems, I think you can rule out $|A \cap B| = 0$ and $|A \cap B| = 2$ using the intersection triangle. To show that there are at least three orbits on $\mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{B}$, note there are at least two, and there are exactly two iff $G$ is $2$-transitive on $\mathcal{B}$. But you can see that $G$ is not $2$-transitive on $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: So this would complete the proof, if you could explain why $(A,B)$ and $(A,B')$ are in the same $G$-orbit if $|A \cap B| = |A \cap B'|$. But maybe there is an easier way to do this exercise.

Comment: @spin Thanks for your comment. No I do not know much about Steiner systems.